# Eigenvalues with no eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a matrix (example 2x2) with 2 distinct eigenvalues have no eigenvetors?
(since, the A-3I as well as A-1I both are coming out as invertible with -3 and -3 with only 0 vector in the nullspace)?

Comment: It should occur to you that perhaps you made an error? Check your work. If there's still an issue, edit your post to show your work.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: You seem to have an example.  What matrix are you talking about?

Comment: Column matrix of vectors (2,1) and (1,2). with |A|= 3 and eigenvalues of 3 and 1

Comment: yes I am aware that i might have made a mistake. But if I did I want someone to tell me what it is. I am not able to see it.

Comment: oops! I figured out. I was subtracting the eigenvalue on all entries!

Comment: A matrix with distinct eigenvalues is always diagonalizable which will have non zero and linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: "yes I am aware that i might have made a mistake. But if I did I want someone to tell me what it is." How can anyone do that if you don't sgow us what you did?

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then that means (by definition) $A\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$ for some $\vec{v}$.

If such a $\vec{v}$ exists, then it's an eigenvector. If such a $\vec{v}$ doesn't exist, then $\lambda$ isn't an eigenvalue (again by definition).

Answer (score 3):

As Draconis wrote, the usual definition of an eigenvalue already states that there's an eigenvector. But let's assume you do an unusual definition that says “an eigenvalue is a root of the characteristic polynomial” (normally that's a theorem, but let's assume that this is your definition).

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(x) = \det(xI - A)$ (sometimes it is defined with the opposite sign, but that's irrelevant for the roots), where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Now if $\lambda$ is a root of the polynomial, that means $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I-A) = 0$. But that implies that $\lambda I - A$ is not invertible, that is, its null space is of positive dimension.

Be $v$ a non-zero element of that null space. Then we have, by definition, $(\lambda I - A)v = 0$. Basic algebra then shows that this is equivalent to $Av = \lambda v$. In other words, $v$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

If a matrix has an eigenvalue, then pretty much by definition (or an easy theorem), it has an eigenvector.

Comment: By definition, yes?

Comment: @mjw I didn't want to exclude the possibility that someone starts with a weird definition, as suggested in celtschk 's answer

Comment: Okay, I see.  Nice that he started without defining rife vectors yet showed they must exist!

Answer (score 0):

*By definition*, a matrix has eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$ when $A \mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{x}$ holds for some $\lambda$ and a non-zero vector $\mathbf{x}$.

To address the matrix example in the comments ...

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 =1$ and $\lambda_2=3$.

The eigenvectors are given by

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{x}_1 =  \begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-}1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix} 3x \\ 3y \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{x}_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: x2 gives the answer 3x,3y alright.

Comment: X2 gives the 3x,3y. But the X1...does not give 1x,1y.......?

Comment: $\mathbf{x}_1=(1,-1)^T.$

Comment: you are right. x1 gives 1x, -1y. Thank you very much. You have been very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.